# Multiple mouse event as3

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

I got a MovieClip that is listening to mouse over and out events.
Inside this movie clip I want to show a button when mouse over.

The problem is that movie clip gets the mouse out event when moving to the button area.
I want him to get mouse out event only when living his rect area.

I found one solution: to make mouse position calculation and compare them to my movieClip position to detect if I should handle or ignore the event.

But is there more simple, more Adobe solution?

**Edit**: The inner button need to receive mouse events as well

Comment: Does the solution you're talking about use a mouse_move or enter_frame listener instead and comparing mouse cords with `hitTestPoint()` each pass? I've resorted to these two listeners for 'mouse hovering' events instead of the individual listeners for more flexibility and have never looked back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `mouseChildren = false` for your `MovieClip` or use `ROLL_OVER` and `ROLL_OUT`, [here](http://www.wastedpotential.com/flash-as3-target-vs-currenttarget/)'s a great article on the subject

Comment: If that website is ever taken offline, this answer is useless. Make more of an effort next time..

Comment: Should I delete it and add as a comment instead? I'm not sure about guidelines of stackoveflow in that case. The page provides valuable information for now.

Answer (score 1):

ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT events should work (use them instead of MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT).

Comment: No its not working, I added logs and I saw that every time that I get ROLL_OVER event MOUSE_OVER is fired as well and the same with roll out

Answer (score 0):

Does the inner button need to receive MouseEvents as well?  If not, just set it's

```
button.mouseEnabled = false;
```

or you can set the parent movie clip's

```
movieclip.mouseChildren = false;
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT events, which will take into account children of the event target

Comment: yes the button need to receive events too. When am I getting roll out event?